# How to vertically and horizontally centre text with a variating font size in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, position, css-position

I'm trying to create a simple chrome extension that allows the user to set a minimum font size that can be displayed on a web page (this is useful for visually impaired people that cant see small font sizes)

The extension will just look through the web page and if there's any font set lower than the user specified minimum font size, if so then the font size will be increased accordingly.

My problem occurs whilst using the extension UI (the popup). 
I want the letters 'abc' to be in the very centre of the box, vertically and horizontally, but whenever I press the increase font size button the letters 'abc' move off centre, even the text is aligned centre, line height is specified and vertical align is set to middle.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

```js
var FS = 20;
var abc = document.getElementById("tester");

var SmlBtn = document.getElementById("SizeMns");
var BigBtn = document.getElementById("SizePls");

if(SmlBtn != null){
    SmlBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        FS = FS - 1;
  console.log(FS);
  abc.style.fontSize = FS;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'fontSize': FS}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    console.log('your font size has been saved to ' + FS.toString());
  });
    });
}

if(BigBtn != null){
 BigBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  FS = FS + 1;
  console.log(FS);
  abc.style.fontSize = FS;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'fontSize': FS}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    console.log('your font size has been saved to ' + FS.toString());
  });
 });
}
```

```css
html {
    text-align: center;
    width: 290px;
 height: 590px;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 590px;
    min-width: 285px;
    max-width: 290px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'PT Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'FreeSans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #43435e;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.header {
 display: block;
 background-color:#00b7f1;
 color: #;
 padding:;
 height:50px;
 line-height: 46px;
 font-size:25;
 font-weight:600
}

.content {
 position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 290px;
 height: 46px;
 line-height: 40px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,80,0.6);
}

#tester {
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding:;
}
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="header">Increase Font Size</div>
    <p id="tester" font-size="FS">abc</p>
   <div class="content">
    <button type="button" id="SizeMns">-</button>
    <button type="button" id="SizePls">+</button>
   </div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have some java script that changes the font size of the letters 'abc' by increments of + or - 1 depending on what button you press.

For some reason the java script behind these buttons didn't work at all in this editor (maybe because it's written for an extension and not for a normal web page) so i left it out as it just caused an unrelated error (the script works perfectly in the extension)

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I've just posted the Javascript for you, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try sth like I quickly implemented in codePen, it will keep font vertically and horizontally aligned.

http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/bZKrpx

Basically to align vertically the 'abc' label, you need a reference box to which heights this label will be aligned. I create it with :before attribute in my code example, but you could just put a  or whatever in #tester  before 'abc' text and style it the same way as :before is styled and you will accomplish the same thing.

```
.tester:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height : 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

the box has 100% heights of its parent, which is #tester . I put #tester position to be absolute and have full height of .wrapper so you may change the height of the widget just by setting height of the wrapper, 'abc' will always be in the middle of .wrapper and .tester height.

Nevertheless, now when you change the size of the font then abc will be centered vertically and horizontally, I hope it is what you wanted to accomplish.

So you may try changing font size in .tester class in my example to see 'abc' being automatically aligned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
This almost works however the variable 'FS' no longer effects the displayed font size of 'abc'. 
I've added the Javascript now just so you know how it works

Comment: I updated my codePen, [link](http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/bZKrpx), with js that works. I also added **FS** variable initialization at begining so the initial font size will be taken from **.tester** class and can be set in css. But basically to make your js code work, you need to set `abc.style.fontSize = FS + 'px';` so add 'px' at the end, so style can be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Brilliant this works! 
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<body align="center">
    <p id="tester" font-size="FS">abc</p>
</body>
```